# Referencing Excel Userform Control Name Value From String (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Typically when referencing a userform control value in Excel VBA I would enter something to the effect of radiobutton.value

However, I want to be able to use a string as the name of the user control. The idea behind this would be to dynamically be able to generate the control name and reference a value from it.

For example I may want to reference ctradiobutton.value one time, and etradiobutton.value the next, these controls already exist on the form, I just want to reference a different name of the control from a string created on the current iteration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't change the code name of a control once it's on a userform

Comment: You'll get a runtime error 382, it's not possible to set the control's `.Name` property at run-time. Perhaps you can use another property like `.Caption` to control your process flow.

Comment: @Kyle I think I may have been unclear, I am not trying to change the control name on the form, but rather get the value from it in my code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this (where `Me` is the UserForm)

```
Me.Controls("TextBox1").Value
```