# Using UserForm and Textbox Name as arguments for a function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform with many textboxes (describe paramenter of tests). I want to use function in order to check each textbox if it's value is in specific range. Allowed values ranges are appearing in excel sheet "T_list) - for each parameter there is different range.If the value of textbox is in the range, the function will return "true", otherwise it will return "false".

Here is how i call to this function:

```
g = CheckGreen(Test_Procedure, CWS1, 1)
msgbox(g)
```

**Test_Procedure**- name of userform, **CWS1** - name of specific textbox, **1** - the first range of value (in the table in the eacel sheet T_list)

Here is the code of the function which doesn't work, since the txtbox argument is get the value of the cell and not the taxtbox name. what i'm doing wrong?

```
Public Function CheckGreen(formName As UserForm, txtbox As MSForms.TextBox, i As Integer) As Boolean
  If formName.txtbox.Value >= Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 0).Value And formName.txtbox.Value <= Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 1).Value Then
formName.txtbox.BackColor = &HFF00& ' Green
Sheets("Test_Data").Range("D_Start").Offset(T_R, 8).Value = formName.txtbox.Value
CheckGreen = True
Else
formName.txtbox.BackColor = &H3535FD ' Red
Sheets("Test_Data").Range("D_Start").Offset(T_R, 8).Value = formName.txtbox.Value
CheckGreen = False
End If
End Function
```

*****edited according to @Banana comment:

this is my function code using the string option (per @Banana comment):

```
Public Function CheckGreen1(formName As UserForm, txtbox As String, i As Integer) As Boolean
If formName.Controls(txtbox).Value >= Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 0).Value And formName.Controls(txtbox).Value <= Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 1).Value Then
formName.Controls(txtbox).BackColor = &HFF00& ' Green
Sheets("Test_Data").Range("D_Start").Offset(T_R, 8).Value = formName.Controls(txtbox).Value
CheckGreen1 = True
Else
formName.Controls(txtbox).BackColor = &H3535FD ' Red
Sheets("Test_Data").Range("D_Start").Offset(T_R, 8).Value = formName.Controls(txtbox).Value
CheckGreen1 = False
End If

End Function
```

Here is how i call the function:

```
g = CheckGreen(CWS1.Value, 1, CWS1)
```

This option is still doesn't work sinse the value now is string, and the IF equation doesn't recognize the value as number, and go alwayse to 'False' (even if the value is in the allowed range).

Please your assistance, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing Excel Userform Control Name Value From String (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083717/referencing-excel-userform-control-name-value-from-string-vba)

Comment: @Banana - it's not the same topic, i need to know how to add textbox name as argument in function.

Comment: a name is just a string, and you pass it as any other string: `"CWS1"`, and you use it as described in the link from my first comment.

Comment: i've tried to put string inside the function argument, it's still doesn't work. can you help me with the syntax?

Comment: this is my code:Function CheckGreen(Tvalue As Double, i As Integer, cell As String) As Boolean


    If Tvalue >= Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 0).Value And Tvalue <= Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 1).Value Then
    Test_Procedure.cell.BackColor = &HFF00& ' Green
    Sheets("Test_Data").Range("D_Start").Offset(T_R, 8).Value = Tvalue
    CheckGreen = True
    Else
    Test_Procedure.cell.BackColor = &H3535FD ' Red
    Sheets("Test_Data").Range("D_Start").Offset(T_R, 8).Value = Tvalue
    CheckGreen = False
    End If



End Function

Comment: please edit your question and put it there, dont paste blocks of code in the comments...

Comment: i've added it now

Comment: change to: `g = CheckGreen(Test_Procedure, "CWS1", 1)` and `txtbox As string` and `formName.controls(txtbox).Value`

Comment: @Banana thanks a lot for the syntax advise! now the code is running and doesn't stuck, but the code is still need fix. Since the value now is string, and the IF equation doesn't recognize the value as number, and go alwayse to 'False' (even if the value is in the allowed range). I would like to get your advise again, thanks (the new code is edited in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is work by putting the string value in the function CDbl() which convert string to double.