# How do I index an integer "i" with ComboBox names to populate the comboboxes with values from a range?

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, userform

In a model I am building, I currently have a large number of userforms filled with code that populates values into comboboxes. In every case, the items being added are values from select cells. I need this to be variable since it will depend on the client data I import into the model. Here is a sample of what code I currently have:

```
ComboBox1.value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value
ComboBox2.value = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").value
ComboBox3.value = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").value
ComboBox4.value = ActiveSheet.Range("D1").value
Combobox5.value = ActiveSheet.Range("E1").value
... (continues down to n = 50)
```

I am looking to do this more efficiently by indexing the comboboxes. This is what I tried:

```
Dim i as integer
For i = 1 to 50
    ComboBox&i.value = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value
Next
```

This doesn't work, and I'm not sure how to properly combine "i" with "ComboBox".

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083717/referencing-excel-userform-control-name-value-from-string-vba.  Then you can concatenate the string.

Comment: Note: the `&` string-concatenation operator (any operator, really) requires a leading and a trailing space, otherwise `ComboBox&` gets parsed as a `Long` literal because `&` isn't just the string-concatenation operator in VBA, it's also a *type hint* token (it basically replaces `As` clauses in declarations - don't do that), and that will thoroughly confuse the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe a loop like below

```
Dim ct As MSForms.Control
For Each ct In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(ct) = "ComboBox" Then
        ct.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Val(Replace(ct.Name, "ComboBox", ""))).Value
    End If
Next ct
```